# Does logrotate.conf override the config of the submodules?

Tags: rsyslog, logrotate, ubuntu-18.04

I wonder which of the logs takes precedence over the other.

Looking at rsyslog defined here, it defines daily rotation and keeping them for 30 days.

> vim /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog

```
/var/log/syslog
{
        rotate 30
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty
        delaycompress
        compress
        postrotate
                /usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate
        endscript
}
```

Then we have the main config, that rotates weekly and keeps 4 weeks at a time.

> vim /etc/logrotate.conf

```
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# use the syslog group by default, since this is the owning group
# of /var/log/syslog.
su root syslog

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d
```

Which one overrides the other one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rules are simply evaluated as they are read, and the last setting encountered overrides previous settings.

As the `/etc/logrotate.conf` file has the line `include /etc/logrotate.d` as last, the files in that directory are also processed after the main config file. Hence the `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` file will override the settings in `/etc/logrotate.conf`.

The point is that you can set default values in the main config file, and override those if necessary for individual log files.